# Google Chrome on Windows 8.1 in VirtualBox on OS X 10.9 looks funny

Tags: google-chrome, virtualbox, windows-8.1, opera

I am running VirtualBox (4.3.6) on Mac OS X (10.9.1). I just upgraded my virtual machine from Windows 8 to 8.1 (Enterprise).

I installed Google Chrome in the virtual machine, but when I launch it, it looks like this:

[image: Google Chrome looks funny]

Opera also has this problem, so I suspect it has something to do with the Webkit engine.

[image: Opera looks funny, too]

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome and deleted any Chrome settings from my AppData folder. I have never seen this before. What is causing it and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried any other browser based on Webkit, for ex. current version of Opera?
My guess it's related to emulation of Windows environment and browser engine (thought it's indeed weird).

Comment: @Battlefist Good idea. Turns out Opera is also affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the Webkit engine trying to use GPU hardware acceleration in the virtual machine. There is [an open VirtualBox bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11576) that describes a similar problem.

You can resolve this problem by either disabling **3D Acceleration** for the virtual machine or asking Google Chrome not to use it.

#### Option 1: Disabling 3D Acceleration

Open the settings for your virtual machine. In the **Display** section, on the **Video** tab, uncheck *Enable 3D Acceleration*.

[image: Disable 3D Acceleration]

#### Option 2: Running Chrome without hardware acceleration

Find the shortcut that you use to launch Chrome. Right-click the shortcut and select **Properties**. On the **Shortcut** tab, in the **Target:** section, add `--disable-gpu` to the end. The full text for the Target should be something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-gpu
```

[image: Chrome shortcut properties]

When you launch Chrome with this shortcut, hardware acceleration will be turned off and the window will render correctly.